# SearchIndexer.exe faulting on Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-media-player, windows-search

I've had Windows 8 running on my laptop since it went RTM, but since about 2 or 3 days ago I haven't been able to use my Windows Media Network Sharing Service to watch movies on my Xbox.  I finally decided to investigate a little bit and it turns out that service isn't running due to a service dependency that isn't running.  The dependency is the "Windows Search" service.

When I try to run it, it fails and if I look in the Application Event Log I see this:

```
Faulting application name: SearchIndexer.exe, version: 7.0.9200.16433, time stamp: 0x50763415
Faulting module name: ESENT.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x5010aad8
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000002056b3
Faulting process id: 0xfdc
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce395021b94eb3
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\SearchIndexer.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\ESENT.dll
Report Id: 5f84cb8e-a543-11e2-be7e-68a3c4f66910
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is occurring?  It worked fine for months up until just a few days ago.

Laptop: HP ProBook 4530s, Core I5, 8G RAM, Win8 Pro

Which reminds me - I did just upgrade from 4 to 8 gigs of RAM a little over a week ago, but I don't see why that would be causing the problem.  The laptop has been very stable and nothing weird has happened since then (except this).

Thank you!

EDIT:

I forgot to mention, I followed the steps that they described over on [this technet forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/38a0ac31-501d-4b84-9b75-5d64fd684e10/) by doing a `sfc /scannow` and analyzing the `cbs.log` file for corrupt files but I don't seem to have any.  I spent quite a bit of time reading up on how to analyze that log file and everything seems good.  `sfc /scannow` reports "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations" upon completion of the command.  That seemed to fix the problem for several people, but not me...

EDIT 2:

I just found this [Windows Search Troubleshooter](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_search/en-us) on support.microsoft.com, but still no luck.  It didn't seem to do anything...

Answer (score 1):

Rebuilding the search index might help, through `Control Panel` - `Indexing Options` - `Advanced` - `Rebuild`.